# Using python function from other python file and subsequent class?

Tags: python, class, module

I have been learning working with classes in python after learning OOPs in c++.
I am working on a project, where I have a class defined in one file, and an important function to be used in the class in the seperate file.
I have to call the class in the first file, but I am getting the ImportError.
Great, if you could help.

try1.py

```
from try2 import prnt

class a:
    def __init__(self):
        print("started")
    def func1(self):
        print("func1")

prnt()
```

try2.py

```
from try1 import a

b = a()
b.func1()

def prnt():
    b.func()
```

As for eg, in the above example, when I am running try1.py, I am getting an ImportError: cannot import name 'prnt'.

Comment: cyclic imports are never good.

Comment: Bad approach. I'd consider removing the `import` and the `prnt()` call in try1 and just run try2. All `prnt()` does is replicate `print()` an already-available function in Python.

Answer (score 0):

You absolutely need to redesign your project. Even if you *did* manage to get away with the cyclic imports (ie by moving the `import` to inside the function - but **don't** do it) you will still get a `NameError: name 'b' is not defined`  since `b` is not define in `prnt`.

Unless `prnt` can't be defined in class `a` (why?), consider defining `prnt` in a third, "utils" file and import it in both `try1.py` and `try2.py` and pass an object to it so it can access all of its attributes.

Comment: Hey @Deepspace, I had been trying to imitate this cpp code. Is there any other alternative to do this? The two cpp codes are: try1.cpp                       #include "try2.h"

void a::prnt(){
 func1();
}

int main(){
 a ab();
 ab.func1();
}                                                                                                            and the second try2.h is                                                                            #include<iostream>

class a{

private:
 void func1(){
  std::cout << "func1";
 }
 void prnt();
};

Answer (score -2):

Just run your code, **read the error**, and deduct something from it.
When you run it, here is the error message :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Kilian\Desktop\Code\Garbage\tmp.py", line 7, in <module>
    from temp2 import prnt
  File "C:\Users\Kilian\Desktop\Code\Garbage\temp2.py", line 1, in <module>
    from tmp import a
  File "C:\Users\Kilian\Desktop\Code\Garbage\tmp.py", line 7, in <module>
    from temp2 import prnt
ImportError: cannot import name prnt
```

Your script is trying to import *something* it already has tried to import earlier on. Python is probably deducing that it can't import it. :)

Comment: Thanks for the downvote, but would you care explaining whoever gave me this ?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but others might have because they want to see a little more guidance. While it is useful to explain the problem in greater detail, it might leave the OP in a position of "Ok, I now see that my code is broken for this reason, but what can I do about it?". Perhaps you could recommend an alternative way to arrange the components of the project.